# I have a streaming pipeline, if i increase the Eventhub partitions from 64 to 128, will that lead to data loss?

Tags: azure-eventhub

I have Azure eventhubs created and running on a "Dedicated" cluster. Currently it is at 64 partitions, how do i ensure that there is no data loss when it is increased to 128 partitions?

Note:

1. Order of events does not matter in this scenario
2. Events can be written to any partitions(round robin fashion)
3. The consumer of this Eventhub is a function app running on I2:64 dedicated app service plan.

Answer (score 1):

Partition scale-out should not cause data loss. Producers may see intermittent failures during scale-out however if your code is properly retrying failed operations then you should really not worry. For the sake of peace of mind, you can first execute a drill on a test eventhub and see scale-out handled w/o any issues.

Btw, make sure consumers are properly configured to receive from new partitions as well.